# Performing date arithmetic while updating table value

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried every possible bracket combination but I just can't get this line to work!

I also tried looking for the solution but I can't seem to find anything similar. I hope someone can shed some light on my ignorance ^^.

```
UPDATE contact_info SET birthday= CURDATE() - TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) % 50000 WHERE contactID=1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you attempting to subtract some strange number of seconds from a date and assigning it to a field called `birthday`?  The logic doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm completely new to mysql. It's a part of the homework I have to do actually, I'll post it here: You will create a statement that will modify the existing record for President Destler to change his birthday by subtracting X days from current date. X is calculated with the statement “SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) % 50000;”. The calculation formula should be “embedded” to the “update” statement. After the update has been executed, select and display the changed birthdate.

Comment: I think you want [DATE_ADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the expression you calculate to an `INTERVAL` specifying the number of days. Then use `DATE_SUB` to subtract the interval from the current date.

```
UPDATE contact_info
SET birthday = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) % 50000) DAY)
WHERE contactID = 1;
```

Comment: I just tried that thanks to @Joachim Isaksson, thanks to both of you! :)